# Polynomial functions on a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, symplectic-geometry

If one views $\Bbb R ^{2n}$ as the cotangent bundle of $\Bbb R ^n$, with coordinates $(q_1, \dots, q_n, p_1, \dots, p_n)$, then in order to do classical Hamiltonian mechanics on it one considers classical observables which are polynomial functions in $q$ and $p$.

If one considers now an abstract smooth manifold (endowed with whatever supplementary structure makes your life easier, such as a Riemannian or a symplectic one), can one come up with an analogous concept to the one of "polynomial function"?

Comment: Well, a holomorphic embedding into projective space would make my life easy...

Comment: @MikeMiller: ...which would require the manifold to be compact, among others, and have a complex analytic structure. No, this is too much! Otherwise, I would have considered algebraic varieties from the beginning. Let's stay in a purely real-differentiable context!

Comment: I figured that would not make you happy :)

Comment: Thought: Suppose I have some structure (symplectic, say) on $M$ and $N$. From this structure, and this structure alone, I want to define a class of maps $M \to N$ that I should call polynomials. Then shouldn't precomposition with an automorphism of M also be a polynomial? If this is the case, then I think the symplectomorphism group is probably too big to be your structure.